# How to avoid a functional cyclic dependency in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

There's a particular JavaScript pattern that has always bothered me, and I never really figured out the proper way to solve it. Instead I usually just ignore it because 99% of JavaScript interpreters support function hoisting so no run-time errors arise.

Consider the following:

```
function onOpen()
{
    console.log("Connected!");
    ws.removeEventListener("open", onOpen);
    ws.removeEventListener("error", onError);
}

function onError()
{
    console.log("Failed to connect!");
    ws.removeEventListener("message", onMessage);
    ws.removeEventListener("error", onError);
}

var ws = new WebSocket("...");
ws.addEventListener("open", onOpen);
ws.addEventListener("error", onError);
```

In this code, within the `onOpen` function, I'm referencing `onError` before `onError` has been defined lower in the code. This isn't actually a problem, because the `onOpen` method won't run until after `onError` has been defined, but it's still bad practice and trips up [ESLint's no-use-before-define rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define)

In a more general sense, this is an error that will arise whenever two functions exist that each need to reference each other:

```
function a(x) {
    return x === 1 ? b(x) : 2;
}
function b(x) {
    return x === 2 ? a(x) : 1;
}
```

Is there a design pattern for eliminating this circular dependency? In my simple generic example the easy solution is "only have one function":

```
function a(x) {
    return x === 1 ? 1 : 2;
}
```

However when binding event listeners this doesn't always seem possible.

Comment: I don't want to get into a religious war, but… some eslint rules are not worth it. Relying on function hoisting is not a bad practice, *especially* in this case I'd say it is perfectly good and readable JavaScript, and you're wasting your time trying to work around a non-issue.

Comment: BTW, some recursive functional patterns *need* function hoisting. Enforcing that eslint rule simply makes your code *less expressive*, not better.

Comment: And finally, contrary to what you imply, function hoisting *does* allow you to actually **call** the function "before" (lexically) its declaration. As long as you don't redefine the same function multiple times or shadow the same identifier (and *useful* eslint rules should easily prevent that), there is no way to create a bug because of function hoisting.

Comment: "*99% of JavaScript interpreters support function hoisting*" - uh, if it doesn't support declarations then it's not a JavaScript interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a real problem, because usually everything works fine. Also you worry about the fact that you mention `onError` before it is declared, but you don't care about mentioning `ws`. But if yous still need to solve this, I hope this approach will do the work.

```
var eventListenerListOnOpen = [];
var eventListListenerOnError = [];
var eventListListenerOnMessage = [];

var ws;

function removeListedEventListeners(object, eventName, eventListenerList) {
  eventListenerList.forEach(function(listener) {
    object.removeEventListener(eventName, listener);
  });
}

function onOpen() {
  removeListedEventListeners(ws, "open", eventListenerListOnOpen);
  removeListedEventListeners(ws, "error", eventListenerListOnError);
}

function onError() {
  removeListedEventListeners(ws, "message", eventListenerListOnMessage);
  removeListedEventListeners(ws, "error", eventListenerListOnError);
}

ws = new WebSocket("...");
ws.addEventListener("open", onOpen);
eventListenerListOnOpen.push(onOpen);
ws.addEventListener("error", onError);
eventListenerListOnError.push(onError);
```

Comment: Nothing really prevents moving my instantiation of `ws` above the function definitions. That was just an oversight as I scribbled down the question. That said, I really like this answer since it provides a generic solution that could be applied in alternate scenarios, and actually looks like a design pattern.

Answer (score 3):

> It's still bad practice and trips up [ESLint's no-use-before-define rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define)

No, it's not a bad practice, it's very much a necessity. It is the preferred pattern when you have a circular functional dependency. Configure your ESLint accordingly (with `{ "functions": false }`).

> Is there a design pattern for eliminating this circular dependency?

Not really. There are several workarounds however, such as declaring the function up-front with a `var` (which is enough to [make ESLint happy](https://eslint.org/demo/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoidmFyIGY7XHJcbmYoKTtcclxuZnVuY3Rpb24gZigpIHt9Iiwib3B0aW9ucyI6eyJwYXJzZXJPcHRpb25zIjp7ImVjbWFWZXJzaW9uIjo2LCJzb3VyY2VUeXBlIjoic2NyaXB0IiwiZWNtYUZlYXR1cmVzIjp7fX0sInJ1bGVzIjp7InByZWZlci1wcm9taXNlLXJlamVjdC1lcnJvcnMiOjIsIm5vLXVzZS1iZWZvcmUtZGVmaW5lIjoyfSwiZW52Ijp7ImVzNiI6dHJ1ZX19fQ==)). Alternatively, you could pass a reference to the function around via parameters:

```
function _a(x, f) {
    return x === 1 ? f(x) : 2;
}
function b(x) {
    return x === 2 ? _a(x, b) : 1;
}
function a(x) {
    return _a(x, b);
}
```

Other crazy hacks with closures, following up on the Y combinator idea, are imaginable. This is not really suitable for your event listener scenario though.

Comment: I guess the reason I think it's bad practice is because in many other languages (for instance, in C++) you at least have to provide function signatures before you use them, even if the implementation comes later. That said, this is less of a "I can't do my job because ESLint is mad" and more of a "The fact that ESLint has a rule against this suggests there's a workaround, but I could never figure out what it was"

Comment: @stevendesu That many other (older) languages have a *deficiency* doesn't make this bad practice :-) Most modern languages do not require forward declarations.