# How should I refactor this code to prevent function was used before it was defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, eslint

I'm getting this error 
`'subscribe' was used before it was defined.eslint(no-use-before-define)` here:

```
    const { values, handleChange, handleSubmit } = useForm(subscribe);

    function subscribe() {
        axios.post(fAction, values, {headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}} )
        .then((response) => {
            document.querySelector('#js-response-newsletter-message > p').innerText = response.data.message;
        });
    }
```

What should be the approach to follow here?

I tried to switch `function` with `const` however, I'll have the same problem since I'm using `value` inside subscribe().

`useForm()` is being used from another file and it's called after submitting a form (callback() -> subscribe()):

```
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    if (values.email !== undefined && values.email !== '') {
      callback(event);
    }
  };
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837993/how-to-avoid-a-functional-cyclic-dependency-in-javascript/ - I think this is a good place to disable the rule. (Still, it's not clear from the code here that the values *will* be defined in time, which makes the rule violation understandable)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, if you don't want to disable any rules, is declare function up front. Something like this:

```
var subscribe;

const { values, handleChange, handleSubmit } = useForm(subscribe);

function subscribe() {
  axios.post(fAction, values, {headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}} )
        then((response) => {
    document.querySelector('#js-response-newsletter-message > p').innerText = 
        response.data.message;
    });
 }
```

[example in ESLint editor](https://eslint.org/demo#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)

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting strategy, I'm surprised it's allowed. Maybe not the best thing to do, but it works!

Comment: I got into another eslint verification `eslint (no-var)`. 
I managed to make it work this way: 

`let subscribe;`
`subscribe = () => { ... } `